# how to access a document from Main Collection after triggering onCreate cloud function on subcollection document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

so let say I have photos collection like this:

[image]

and the subcollection (likers) like this:
[image]

I want to make a trigger, If a new `likers` document is created, then I want to increase `point` field +=1 in the main Collection document ( `q27yiVv4g7XVgiaG7c7a`). how to get access to that `q27yiVv4g7XVgiaG7c7a` document so I can increase the point?

should be use the code below, but I don't know how to access that document

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('photos/{photoId}/likers/{likersId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a reference to the document using the wildcard `photoId` that you defined in your function along with the ref of the changed document in the snapshot:

```
const photoId = context.params.photoId
const photoRef = snap.ref.firestore.collection('photos').doc(photoId)
```